# Running (system/Jenkins) groovy script on slave while accessing build variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson, jenkins-agent

I'm trying to run a groovy script which is updating the `build.description` during the execution while running a process on a slave node.

My problem is that a "system groovy script' executes only on the master node and 'Jenkins groovy scripts' run on slave nodes but have no access to the `build` variable.

I have a script similar to this one:

```
import hudson.model.* 

// works on slave node
def param = args[0]

// works on master node
//def param = build.getEnvironment(listener).get('Params') 

def ws = new File(".").absolutePath

def myCommand = ws + "\\Something.exe " + param

def proc = myCommand.execute();

// Cannot use on slave
build.description = "Running executable..."

int exitVal = proc.waitFor();

// Cannot use on slave
build.description = "Executable finished"
```

Is there a way to modify the build variable on a "Jenkins Groovy Script" which runs on a slave?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Jenkins pipeline exposes more control on such things.

Following is from script we have. `nodeexpression` could a node name.

```
  node(nodeexpression) {
        println "env :"
        echo sh(script: 'env|sort', returnStdout: true)

        currentBuild.displayName = "branch ${BRANCH}:${MAIL_TO}"
        currentBuild.description = "${BRANCH}:${MAIL_TO} : message -> ${MESSAGE}"
  }
```